# How can I use a time series of values to predict a single number in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to build a machine learning model (LSTM) with tensorflow which predicts a single number from a time series of numbers.

First of all, you can imagine my dataset to look something like this:

| Index | time data | x data | y data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `np.ndarray(shape (1209278,) )` | `np.ndarray(shape (1209278,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 1 | `np.ndarray(shape (1211140,) )` | `np.ndarray(shape (1211140,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 2 | `np.ndarray(shape (1418411,) )` | `np.ndarray(shape (1418411,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Basically, I have time data and at eacht time step I have a corresponding x data point. For each time sequence I want to predict the corresponding single number found in y data.
Easily said I just want my model to predict a number from a time sequence of numbers.
For example like this:

- array([(time_step_1_1, x_val_1_1), (time_step_1_2, x_val_1_2), ...]) => y_val_1
- array([(time_step_2_1, x_val_2_1), (time_step_2_2, x_val_2_2), ...]) => y_val_2
- ...

In this example x_val_1_1 means the first x value of the *first sequence* of data in my dataset, x_val_1_2 means the second x value of the *first sequence* and so on.

On the other hand, x_val_2_1 means the first value of the *second sequence* of data and so on, I think you get it.

It is important to notice, that my x data arrays are NOT of the same length (as you can see in the table above).

I also have a Google colab notebook with a minimal example, which would probably really helpful to understand what I want to do. It can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ToHIrmXHHQC8t9240PK_clO_8iZ45fnq?usp=sharing).
In my current attempt I have used [ragged tensors from tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor) which seem to be a good choice because "They make it easy to store and process data with non-uniform shapes like: Batches of variable-length sequential inputs".
Currently I did not use the time data yet, because it was possible by only using the x_data without paying respect to the time data.
But turns out: It is not. I was able to train my model on very powerful hardware, but the results looked like this:
[image: Model results]

In this graph the blue line is the one that's the data I want to predict, so my y data. The orange line is the result my model currently actually predicts. So it seems like my model tries to find the best *constant* value to fit the curve rather than fitting the actual curve directly.

This fact combined with the problem that I had a lot of out of memory errors like this: `OOM when allocating tensor with shape[22119477696] and type uint8 on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc`
although I was using very powerful hardware (also have a look at this part of the error message `shape[22119477696]`, which clearly is an insanely big array).
Clearly something is wrong with my model, but I don't know what and why.

All in all I hope that somebody with a bit more experience could know how to tackle this problem, unlike me. Thank you for your time. Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your network isn't large enough? You have 21,025 trainable params but time-series datapoints of length > 1e6. When I was working on an image processing project, if my network was too small I would just get a constant pixel value. Perhaps you are experiencing the same problem. This is speculation, but perhaps you need to satisfy `trainable_params*y_series_length >= x_series_length`. Here, `y_series_length=1`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The network above is very simplified, in my actual network I have about 7-11 million trainable parameters (4-7 LSTM layers with 64-512 Nodes, I have tried different combinations => same results).

Comment: To help with debugging, you can try padding your inputs to a fixed length. This way, you can avoid using a ragged array,

Comment: For the OOM problem, you don't seem to be batching the inputs along axis 0. The network is trying to process all of your data at once, which is impossible,

Comment: I can try to set my input to a fixed length, that would be a good idea. What exactly do you mean by "you don't seem to be batching the inputs along axis 0. The network is trying to process all of your data at once, which is impossible" ?

Comment: The shape of your training `X` data should be `(num_batches,batch_size,padded_seq_length)` and `Y` data should be `(num_batches,batch_size,1)`, not `(num_data_points,padded_seq_length)` and `(num_data_points,1)`. If your network is huge, you may want to set `num_batches=num_data_points` and `batch_size=1`. I did find that if I wanted to use batching, the first layer of my `Sequential` model should be an `Input` layer. This will handle the batching axis automatically, allowing the next layer to have inpput shape `(padded_seq_length,)` instead of `(batch_size,padded_seq_length)`.

Comment: Hi, I have asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457069/why-does-my-lstm-model-predict-wrong-values-although-the-loss-is-decreasing I followed your tip to try to use a fixed length so I can use ordinary numpy arrays instead of RaggedTensors. Maybe you can have a look!

Comment: I saw the new question. I'm not very familiar with LSTMs, so since the programming bugs seem to be solved, I'll let an expert handle design questions. Good luck!